# Video js fill div without black behind video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I tried using fill mode and this is what I get.

What I would like is not having black left and right of video, because controls also span 100% but ideally they would be the same as video width not wider.

I want to fill available area but not make video bigger than its natural size, and I dont want vertical scroll if video is bigger than it fits (so I dont use fluid option).

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  
  <div style="width:100%; height:300px;">
  <video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-fill" controls muted preload="auto" data-setup="{}" >
    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use  measure in pixels.
Give aspect-ratio:16/9; or something.
and give to video element "object-fit" property

```css
.video-wrap {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover; /*  if you want fill all area  (its can 
 be crop video */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  
<div class="video-wrap">
  <video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-fill" controls muted preload="auto" data-setup="{}" >
    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: The CSS `aspect-ratio` property is supported natively in all major browsers.  If you need support for old browsers, there are [polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-aspect-ratio-polyfill) as well.

Comment: This does not behave as I wished. Video will become wider than its original size as you resize window. Also it has vertical scroll. I want video never the be bigger than parent container and its original size and no scroll.

Comment: Currently there is no scroll and it does not overflow from the container. You may not have deleted the old CSS codes. (scroll looking on StackOverflow, cause height is small. its about body height. just try on your pc) codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/eYLVrqP

if the video is 1920/1080.
It should be aspect-ratio:1920/1080.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can do it if you know the aspect ratio in advance

The key is to make a container for the video, which you carefully predefine to automatically grow to the desired height, based on the available width.

For a 16:9 aspect ratio, set the `padding-bottom` to 9/16 = 56.25%

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* Specific for 16:9 aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-js {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video id="my_video" class="video-js" autoplay controls muted preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not behave as I wished. Video will become wider than its original size as you resize window. Also it has vertical scroll. I want video never the be bigger than parent container and its original size and no scroll.